# Function that shows if shop is open, and if not, when it opens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

I'm trying to make a function that gets current time and based on an array with open hours, shows if the shop is open or closed, and when it closes and opens.

This is my array with hours and it can't change, I mean, the hours can change, but overall how it works not.

```
{
"openHours": [
              { days: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], from: '11:00', to: '22:00' },
              { days: [6], from: '12:00', to: '23:00' },
             ]
}
```

And as you can see, there is no day 0, which is Sunday, because the shop is closed then.

I have this for now

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const [opensAt, setOpensAt] = useState(false);
const [closesAt, setClosesAt] = useState(false);

const checkIfOpen = () => {
    const now = new Date();
    const openedHours = card.openHours.find(i => i.days.includes(now.getDay()));
    const nextDay = new Date(Date.now() + 3600 * 1000 * 24);
    const openedHoursNextDay = card.openHours.find(i => i.days.includes(nextDay.getDay()));

    if (openedHours) {
      const fromHours = new Date().setHours(...openedHours.from.split(':'));
      const toHours = new Date().setHours(...openedHours.to.split(':'));
      if (fromHours <= now.getTime() && now.getTime() <= toHours) {
        setIsOpen(true);
        setClosesAt(openedHours.to);
      } else if (now.getTime() > toHours) {
        setIsOpen(false);
        setOpensAt(openedHoursNextDay.from);
      } else {
        setIsOpen(false);
        setOpensAt(openedHours.from);
      }
    }
  };

return (
        <div className="info-text text-nowrap">
            {isOpen ? `Closed at ${closesAt}` : `Opens at ${opensAt}`}
        </div>
        <div className="info-text">{isOpen ? "Now open" : "Now closed"}</div>
);
```

So I have a problem. If the next day is Sunday, openedHoursNextDay returns undefined, how can I get the next day that has open hours?

Comment: If Sunday ***isn't*** the only possibly closed day then you should specify that in your question. Your claim was that the data ***was*** the data and it can't be changed. Please try to be more upfront with your requirements and behavior. It would be nice to provide some example data and expected results.

Comment: There are a [huge number of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+business+open+and+closed) on this topic already. You should reconsider your data structure so it's more flexible and easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I'd do...

```
const now = new Date();
const openedHours = card.openHours.find(i => i.days.includes(now.getDay()));
const nextDay = new Date(Date.now() + 3600 * 1000 * 24);
var nextAvailableDayOfTheWeek = nextDay.getDay();
var availableDays = new Array();
for ( let index = 0; index < openHours.length; index++ ) { // gathers all available days
    availableDays = availableDays.concat(openHours[index].days);
}
while ( ! availableDays.includes(nextAvailableDayOfTheWeek) ) { // if nextAvailableDayOfTheWeek is not available, go look for the next day that is
    nextAvailableDayOfTheWeek++;
    if ( 7 == nextAvailableDayOfTheWeek ) nextAvailableDayOfTheWeek = 0; // if after saturday then reset to sunday
}
```

Comment: That works only if sunday is the only closed day, what if the e.g. saturday is also closed, or any other day

Comment: Code–only answers aren't particularly helpful. A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Now,

```js
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const [closesAt, setClosesAt] = useState(false);
const [opensAt, setOpensAt] = useState(false);

const checkIfOpen = () => {
  const now = new Date();
  const openedHours = card.openHours.find(i => i.days.includes(now.getDay()));
  const nextDay = new Date(Date.now() + 3600 * 1000 * 24);
  const openedHoursNextDay = card.openHours.find(i => i.days.includes(nextDay.getDay() === 0 ? 1: nextDay.getDay()));

  if (openedHours) {
    const fromHours = new Date().setHours(...openedHours.from.split(':'));
    const toHours = new Date().setHours(...openedHours.to.split(':'));
    if (fromHours <= now.getTime() && now.getTime() <= toHours) {
      setIsOpen(true);
      setClosesAt(openedHours.to);
    } else if (now.getTime() > toHours) {
      setIsOpen(false);
      setOpensAt(openedHoursNextDay.from);
    } else {
      setIsOpen(false);
      setOpensAt(openedHours.from);
    }
  }
};

return
  <div>
      <div className = "info-text text-nowrap" > 
         {isOpen ? `Closed at ${closesAt}` : `Opens at ${opensAt}`} 
      </div> 
      <div className = "info-text" > 
         {isOpen ? "Now open" : "Now closed"} 
      </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, because I need the specific next open day to render when the shop opens

Comment: Ye but that also works only if sunday is the closed day, what if e.g saturday or any other day is closed